# Parsear data a JSON en JS

Tags: javascript, json

Estoy intentado parsear la siguiente información:

```
xoCuenta%5BTipoCuenta%5D%5BCodigoTipoCuenta%5D=3&xoCuenta%5BTipoCuenta%5D%5BDescripcion%5D=Prepago&xoCuenta%5BFechaEgreso%5D=&xoCuenta%5BAgrupacion%5D%5BTipoCuenta%5D%5BCodigoTipoCuenta%5D=3&xoCuenta%5BAgrupacion%5D%5BTipoCuenta%5D%5BDescripcion%5D=Prepago&xoCuenta%5BAgrupacion%5D%5BTipoCuenta%5D%5BEsPospago%5D=false&xoCuenta%5BAgrupacion%5D%5BTipoCuenta%5D%5BTipoBoleto%5D=&xoCuenta%5BAgrupacion%5D%5BTipoCuenta%5D%5BPermiteSaldo%5D=false&xoCuenta%5BAgrupacion%5D%5BTipoCuenta%5D%5BPermitePagoVia%5D=false&xoCuenta%5BAgrupacion%5D%5BTipoCuenta%5D%5BPermiteAbono%5D=false&xoCuenta%5BAgrupacion%5D%5BSubTipoCuenta%5D=1&xoCuenta%5BAgrupacion%5D%5BDescripcionAgrupacion%5D=Prepagos+0%25&xoCuenta%5BAgrupacion%5D%5BTipoTarifa%5D%5BCodigoTarifa%5D=0&xoCuenta%5BAgrupacion%5D%5BTipoTarifa%5D%5BDescripcion%5D=Tarifa+Manual&xoCuenta%5BAgrupacion%5D%5BTipoTarifa%5D%5BPorcentaje%5D=0&xoCuenta%5BAgrupacion%5D%5BTipoTarifa%5D%5BsPorcentaje%5D=0%25&xoCuenta%5BAgrupacion%5D%5BTipoTarifaVenta%5D%5BCodigoTarifa%5D=&xoCuenta%5BAgrupacion%5D%5BTipoTarifaVenta%5D%5BDescripcion%5D=&xoCuenta%5BAgrupacion%5D%5BTipoTarifaVenta%5D%5BPorcentaje%5D=0&xoCuenta%5BAgrupacion%5D%5BTipoTarifaVenta%5D%5BsPorcentaje%5D=0%25&xoCuenta%5BAgrupacion%5D%5BDiasDuracionCuenta%5D=&xoCuenta%5BAgrupacion%5D%5BControlaCategoria%5D=N&xoCuenta%5BAgrupacion%5D%5BControlaPatente%5D=N&xoCuenta%5BAgrupacion%5D%5BRequierePermisoEspecial%5D=false&xoCuenta%5BAgrupacion%5D%5BPermisoModificarCuentasExclusivas%5D=&xoCuenta%5BAgrupacion%5D%5BCodigoTipoCuenta%5D=3&xoCuenta%5BAgrupacion%5D%5BDescripcionTipoCuenta%5D=Prepago&xoCuenta%5BAgrupacion%5D%5BDescripcionTipoTarifa%5D=Tarifa+Manual&xoCuenta%5BAgrupacion%5D%5BDescripcionTipoTarifaVenta%5D=&xoCuenta%5BDescripcion%5D=Prepagos+0%25&xoCuenta%5BCliente%5D%5BNumeroCliente%5D=2&xoCuenta%5BCliente%5D%5BRazonSocial%5D=CLIENTE+PRUEBA1&xoCuenta%5BCliente%5D%5BTarjetaCredito%5D=
```

Los campos están separados por caracteres tales como '%5D%5B' por lo tanto no puedo parsearlo como si fuese un string. Alguna idea?

Comment: Bienvenido! Usa [decodeURI()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURI) y si tienes algun problema edita tu pregunta con lo que has intentado y su error, y sino bórrala, pues no muestras ni un intento ni un error a arreglar, es simplemente una consulta que podrias haber encontrado en google tranquilamente (como yo he hecho). Léete [ask], [tour] y [example] para aprender el funcionamiento básico de este sitio, gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Usa la librería [qs](https://github.com/ljharb/qs) para parsear datos en ese formato a un objecto de javascript:

```js
const yourMessage = "xoCuenta%5BTipoCuenta%5D%5BCodigoTipoCuenta%5D=3&xoCuenta%5BTipoCuenta%5D%5BDescripcion%5D=Prepago&xoCuenta%5BFechaEgreso%5D=&xoCuenta%5BAgrupacion%5D%5BTipoCuenta%5D%5BCodigoTipoCuenta%5D=3&xoCuenta%5BAgrupacion%5D%5BTipoCuenta%5D%5BDescripcion%5D=Prepago&xoCuenta%5BAgrupacion%5D%5BTipoCuenta%5D%5BEsPospago%5D=false&xoCuenta%5BAgrupacion%5D%5BTipoCuenta%5D%5BTipoBoleto%5D=&xoCuenta%5BAgrupacion%5D%5BTipoCuenta%5D%5BPermiteSaldo%5D=false&xoCuenta%5BAgrupacion%5D%5BTipoCuenta%5D%5BPermitePagoVia%5D=false&xoCuenta%5BAgrupacion%5D%5BTipoCuenta%5D%5BPermiteAbono%5D=false&xoCuenta%5BAgrupacion%5D%5BSubTipoCuenta%5D=1&xoCuenta%5BAgrupacion%5D%5BDescripcionAgrupacion%5D=Prepagos+0%25&xoCuenta%5BAgrupacion%5D%5BTipoTarifa%5D%5BCodigoTarifa%5D=0&xoCuenta%5BAgrupacion%5D%5BTipoTarifa%5D%5BDescripcion%5D=Tarifa+Manual&xoCuenta%5BAgrupacion%5D%5BTipoTarifa%5D%5BPorcentaje%5D=0&xoCuenta%5BAgrupacion%5D%5BTipoTarifa%5D%5BsPorcentaje%5D=0%25&xoCuenta%5BAgrupacion%5D%5BTipoTarifaVenta%5D%5BCodigoTarifa%5D=&xoCuenta%5BAgrupacion%5D%5BTipoTarifaVenta%5D%5BDescripcion%5D=&xoCuenta%5BAgrupacion%5D%5BTipoTarifaVenta%5D%5BPorcentaje%5D=0&xoCuenta%5BAgrupacion%5D%5BTipoTarifaVenta%5D%5BsPorcentaje%5D=0%25&xoCuenta%5BAgrupacion%5D%5BDiasDuracionCuenta%5D=&xoCuenta%5BAgrupacion%5D%5BControlaCategoria%5D=N&xoCuenta%5BAgrupacion%5D%5BControlaPatente%5D=N&xoCuenta%5BAgrupacion%5D%5BRequierePermisoEspecial%5D=false&xoCuenta%5BAgrupacion%5D%5BPermisoModificarCuentasExclusivas%5D=&xoCuenta%5BAgrupacion%5D%5BCodigoTipoCuenta%5D=3&xoCuenta%5BAgrupacion%5D%5BDescripcionTipoCuenta%5D=Prepago&xoCuenta%5BAgrupacion%5D%5BDescripcionTipoTarifa%5D=Tarifa+Manual&xoCuenta%5BAgrupacion%5D%5BDescripcionTipoTarifaVenta%5D=&xoCuenta%5BDescripcion%5D=Prepagos+0%25&xoCuenta%5BCliente%5D%5BNumeroCliente%5D=2&xoCuenta%5BCliente%5D%5BRazonSocial%5D=CLIENTE+PRUEBA1&xoCuenta%5BCliente%5D%5BTarjetaCredito%5D="

const javascriptObject = Qs.parse(yourMessage)
console.log(javascriptObject)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/qs/6.11.0/qs.js"></script>
```